# How to have a Guice module use another Guice module?

Tags: java, guice

Let's say I have a Guice module ProdModule that I would like to depend on other GuiceModules, ProdDbModule and ProdPubSubModule.  How would I implement ProdModule's configure()?

Answer (score 57, accepted):

You would [install](https://google.github.io/guice/api-docs/latest/javadoc/com/google/inject/Binder.html#install-com.google.inject.Module-) your other modules

```
protected void configure(){
    install(new ProdDbModule());
    install(new ProdPubSubModule());
    // etc.
}
```

Answer (score 33):

While it can be convenient to use `install`, you don't even need to `install` the other modules as long as you provide all the necessary modules when you create your `Injector`:

```
Injector injector = Guice.createInjector(new ProdDbModule(),
    new ProdPubSubModule(), new ProdModule());
```

This can give you more flexibility to change out just one of these modules in your entry point class without needing to modify `ProdModule` itself. You can also indicate in a module what bindings it requires other modules to provide using the `requireBinding` methods.

Answer (score 11):

You can use `Modules.combine` to create a new module that contains all the other modules. (See [this link](http://google.github.io/guice/api-docs/latest/javadoc/index.html?com/google/inject/util/Modules.html))

The differences:

- this is not subject to tight coupling modules like `install()`
- this creates a `Module` rather than an injector, which means you can easily add different modules to the injector.

### Code

```
import com.google.inject.util.Modules;
Module module = Modules.combine(new ProdDbModule(),
  new ProdPubSubModule(), new ProdModule());
Injector injector = Guice.createInjector(module);
```

Comment: And what would be the difference w.r.t. simply calling `Guice.createInjector(new ProdDbModule(),
  new ProdPubSubModule(), new ProdModule())`?

Comment: nothing. combine is useful if you want to share the same list of modules in multiple places, and perhaps want a tree of modules instead of a list.